# Passing jquery variable by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem - I need to pass jQuery variable by ajax request.

I get two jquery variables and a lot of not useful output in file ajax.php and somehow I need to get only values of those variables.

Something like:

```
$.get('ajax.php', function (data) {
alert('data.var1'); alert(data.var2)
});
```

Comment: do you want to **retrieve** those variables FROM ajax or **send** data TO the actual server? this is a bit unclear for me - also, can you provide a sample output from ajax.php?

Comment: I want to retrieve those variables from ajax.php an example of output would be something like: <script>var1='aaaa'; var2='vvvv'; function blabla() { }</script>some html code here...

Comment: can you modify your php file so it only outputs the needed variables as json? This would be better.

Comment: that's the problem I can't express those variables as php code.

Comment: so you don't have access to the php file? So it is not on the same server?

Comment: it's on my server I just can't express those variables as php code..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to append the data to the page - you can append it to hidden div for example and then it will become part of the page data and you will have script access to it.
Like this:

```
$.get('ajax.php', function (data) {    
    $('#yourDivId').html(data);    
    alert(var2); //no need for data.var2 
});
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, how could I access it?

Answer (score 0):

If your *ajax.php* file returns an actual SCRIPT tag and JavaScript output, you can access those via a global variable, since that's where they get assigned:

```
$.get('ajax.php', function (data) {
  alert(var1); alert(var2);
  // or: alert(window.var1); alert(window.var2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add a script tag to the document you better use pure javascript.

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.src   = "ajax.php";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

If you just want to get some values from a php file you better only request those values without the garbage you don't need. This can be done as json. However you need to modify your php script to output the correct datatype.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php?get=json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON'

})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log("success");
    alert(data.var1+'  '+data.var1);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});


//php
<?php>
if(isset($_GET['get']) &&  $_GET['get']=='json'){
    $ar=array();
    $ar['var1']='hello';
    $ar['var2']='hello';

    echo json_encode($ar);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this if you bring script tag with ajax response,Otherwise you have to create script tag and than add your response to it.

```
    $.get('ajax.php', function (data) {    
        $('yourdiv').html(data);    
        alert(var1); 
    });
```